# How do I assign a callback handler with inline method in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Here is how I implement an inline callback assignment in Objective-C:

```
self.beforeAdjustViews = ^ (UIView* btnView)
{
    // do something
};
```

How do I implement the same thing in Swift 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either assign directly

```
self.beforeAdjustViews = { (button) in 
    // Write Some Code
}
```

or create a reference variable to this call back - usually better when you have a lot of properties or trying to keep you code simple and beautiful

```
let beforAdjustViewsCallBack: (btnView: UIView) -> Void = { button in 
    // Write Some Code
}
```

Also keep in mind that the same rules for retain cycles are applied, So if you don't want to keep a strong reference of the `self` inside the block, you will need to use either `[weak self]` or `[unowoned self]` based on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
self.beforeAdjustViews = { [weak self] (btnView) in 
 ///
}
```